# Renaming columns in a Pandas dataframe with duplicate column names?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df X with columns with duplicate names:

```
In [77]: X_R
Out[77]: 
      dollars  dollars
   0   0.7085   0.5000
```

I want to rename it so that I have:

```
In [77]: X_R
Out[77]: 
       Retail   Cost
   0   0.7085   0.5000
```

Using the Pandas rename function does' work:

```
X_R.rename(index=str, columns={"dollars": "Retail", "dollars": "Cost"})
```

Just gives me two columns named Cost.

How can I rename the columns in this case?

Comment: `X_R.columns = ['Retail','Cost']`?

Comment: how did you get the duplicated column names ?

Comment: Just in case you didn't realize, `{"dollars": "Retail", "dollars": "Cost"}` becomes `{"dollars": "Cost"}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
X_R.columns = ['Retail','Cost']
```

Answer (score 28):

Here is a dynamic solution:

```
In [59]: df
Out[59]:
   a  x  x  x  z
0  6  2  7  7  8
1  6  6  3  1  1
2  6  6  7  5  6
3  8  3  6  1  8
4  5  7  5  3  0

In [60]: d
Out[60]: {'x': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']}

In [61]: df.rename(columns=lambda c: d[c].pop(0) if c in d.keys() else c)
Out[61]:
   a  x1  x2  x3  z
0  6   2   7   7  8
1  6   6   3   1  1
2  6   6   7   5  6
3  8   3   6   1  8
4  5   7   5   3  0
```

Comment: I was wondering how to get the duplicated column names in pandas. Pandas only takes the last column, also if I read the data from file it gives me `x x.1 x.2`.

Comment: @astro123, if you want to preserve duplicates in column names use `mangle_dupe_cols=False` parameter. `df.columns[df.columns.duplicated()]` - will give you duplicated column names

Answer (score 23):

Here is another dynamic solution that I think is nicer

```
In [59]: df
Out[59]:
   a  x  x  x  z
0  6  2  7  7  8
1  6  6  3  1  1
2  6  6  7  5  6
3  8  3  6  1  8
4  5  7  5  3  0
In [61]: class renamer():
             def __init__(self):
                  self.d = dict()

              def __call__(self, x):
                  if x not in self.d:
                      self.d[x] = 0
                      return x
                  else:
                      self.d[x] += 1
                      return "%s_%d" % (x, self.d[x])

          df.rename(columns=renamer())
Out[61]:
   a  x  x_1  x_2  z
0  6   2   7   7  8
1  6   6   3   1  1
2  6   6   7   5  6
3  8   3   6   1  8
4  5   7   5   3  0
```

Comment: thanks for this;  i was able to use this to rename columns before doing a column drop... which apparently has trouble with duplicate column names?

Answer (score 7):

Not directly an answer, but since this a top search result, here is a short and flexible solution to append a suffix to duplicate column names:

```
# A dataframe with duplicated column names
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9]])
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'b']

# Columns to not rename
excluded = df.columns[~df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)]

# An incrementer
import itertools
inc = itertools.count().__next__

# A renamer
def ren(name):
    return f"{name}{inc()}" if name not in excluded else name

# Use inside rename()
df.rename(columns=ren)
```

```
    a   b   b              a  b0  b1
0   1   2   3          0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6    =>    1   4   5   6
2   7   8   8          2   7   8   9
```

Comment: Note that the suffix counter is shared, i.e. if you have multiple sets of duplicates they aren't handled independently. `a, a, b, b` becomes `a0, a1, b2, b3`.

Comment: This is lovely! I used it a loop on a large dictionary of dataframes imported from very messy spreadsheets and it worked perfectly for my needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

[MaxU's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774999/3364939) helped me with this same problem. In this answer, I add in a way to find those duplicated column headers.

First, we make a dictionary of the duplicated column names with values corresponding to the desired new column names. For this, the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) subclass is required.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

renamer = defaultdict()
```

We iterate over the duplicated column names to create a dictionary with keys being the duplicated column name and values being a list of new column names. I have chosen this list to be original name_0, original name_1, and so on.

```
for column_name in df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)].tolist():
    if column_name not in renamer:
        renamer[column_name] = [column_name+'_0']
    else:
        renamer[column_name].append(column_name +'_'+str(len(renamer[column_name])))

print(renamer)
defaultdict(None, {'b': ['b_0', 'b_1', 'b_2', 'b_3'], 'c': ['c_0', 'c_1']})
```

Original dataframe:

```
print(df)
        a   b   b   b   b   c   c   d
Item 0  2   1   0   2   8   3   9   5
Item 1  3   2   7   3   5   4   6   2
Item 2  4   3   8   1   5   7   4   4
Item 3  5   5   3   6   0   5   2   5
```

Rename the duplicated columns by assigning the new names from our renamer defaultdict, leaving the unduplicated columns alone

```
df.rename(
    columns=lambda column_name: renamer[column_name].pop(0)
    if column_name in renamer 
    else column_name
)
        a   b_0 b_1 b_2 b_3 c_0 c_1 d
Item 0  2   1   0   2   8   3   9   5
Item 1  3   2   7   3   5   4   6   2
Item 2  4   3   8   1   5   7   4   4
Item 3  5   5   3   6   0   5   2   5
```

(As a sidenote, a couple of people have questioned why duplicated column names existed in the first place. For myself, I encountered duplicated column names when importing with the [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html) package (to deal with password-protected Excel files). You could also inadvertently create duplicate column names by using `pd.concat`.