# Extract text from a series into new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've tries the following code with the following error message:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

I'm referencing a string series, then why am i getting a "Dataframe" error?

```
df['PO'] =  df['extract'].str.extract(r"(?:^(?=[A-Z\d/-]+$)|\bPO\W*)([A-Z\d/-]+)")
```

Comment: If check `print (df['extract'])` it return duplicated columns `extract` in df?

Comment: yes,  column name comes as:   extract extract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with duplicated columns names, so if select one column `extract` get all columns in DataFrame.

```
print (df['extract'])
```

For deduplicted is simpliest set columns names or [some another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40774787/2901002):

```
df.columns= ['a','b']
```

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @amitsingh - what is not clear?

Comment: 1) why is the columns name  df['extract'] duplicated? Is that a data quality issue? and in my sitaution one of the extracts has data, whereasthe other has only NaN values.

Comment: @amitsingh - `why is the columns name df['extract'] duplicated?` Because data, because some wrong pandas operation, because... not idea.

Comment: @amitsingh - Maybe help me see your complete code before `df['PO'] =  df['extract'].str.extract`

Comment: i'm sorry for being annoying, but thank you for pointing me to the issue. Many thanks!