# Fill Specific Null Values

Tags: python, pandas

For example a dataframe as the Following

| Customer Name | Customer Group |
| --- | --- |
| ABC, PT       | NaN            |
| DEF, PT       | NaN            |
....

the Customer Group field is filled with text before the comma hence the expected output is like this

Customer Name | Customer Group
| --- | --- |
| ABC, PT   |      ABC
| DEF, PT   |      DEF
...

Does anyone know how to code this? I am guessing it will use regex

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: There are columns names with same values, here `Customer Name`, so first use some solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40774787/2901002).

Then use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for all values before `,`:

```
df['Customer Group'] = df['Customer Name'].str.extract('^(.*),')
```

Or:

```
df['Customer Group'] = df['Customer Name'].str.split(',').str[0]
```

If need replace only missing values:

```
df['Customer Group']=df['Customer Group'].fillna(df['Customer Name'].str.extract('^(.*),'))
```

Comment: Hi I tried to apply the code but it showed error like this "value" parameter must be a scalar, dict or Series, but you passed a "DataFrame"

Comment: @CarlosAlberto - It means `print (df['Customer Name'])` return `DataFrame` instead one column?