# Renaming identical column names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `cycle_2` df with the following column names:

```
                 3ls    3rs     3ls      3rs    3
absolute_cost   3.00    9.40    9.40    0.00    6.00
```

Now I need to rename them:
I did the following:

```
cycle_2.rename(columns={cycle_2.columns[0]:'Email', cycle_2.columns[1]:'Flash', cycle_2.columns[2]:'Sms', cycle_2.columns[3]:'UPI', cycle_2.columns[4]:'IVR'})
```

However its printing this out:

```
                 Sms    UPI     Sms     UPI     IVR
absolute_cost   3.00    9.40    9.40    0.00    6.00
```

I am unable to understand why is this happeneing? How can I rename them?

Expected Output:

```
                Email   Flash   Sms     UPI     IVR
absolute_cost   3.00    9.40    9.40    0.00    6.00
```

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774787/renaming-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-with-duplicate-column-names

Comment: or simply `df.columns = ['Email', 'Flash', 'Sms', 'UPI', 'IVR']`

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the possible solutions

```
df.columns = ['Email', 'Flash', 'Sms', 'UPI', 'IVR']
```

Answer (score 0):

cycle_2.columns = ['Email', 'Flash', 'Sms', 'UPI', 'IVR']

Comment: it's not really useful to provide the same answer as already provided once as comment, once as answer and many more times in duplicates

Comment: i was typing my answer and went away for sometime and meanwhile you commented and others answered