# Keep first instance of columns with duplicate name but different types in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I aggregate data from a lot of sources and ended up in this situation where I have a large number of duplicate columns that are virtually similar but one of them is of type `int` while the other is of type `float` :

[image]

I'd like to know if there is a way to automatically keep only the first instance of each column that has the same name as another?

I was pointed to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774787/renaming-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-with-duplicate-column-names) and I could use

```py
data.columns[data.columns.duplicated(keep=False)].tolist()
```

to get the names of duplicated columns

and then, continuing to adapt this answer to this problem looks like this :

```py
for column_name in data.columns[data.columns.duplicated(keep=False)].tolist():
    if column_name not in renamer:
        renamer[column_name] = [column_name]
    else:
        renamer[column_name].append(column_name +'_to_drop_'+str(len(renamer[column_name])))
        
data = data.rename(
    columns=lambda column_name: renamer[column_name].pop(0)
    if column_name in renamer 
    else column_name
)
        
data = data.drop([col for col in flow_curves.columns if '_to_drop_' in col],axis=1)
```

It does work now. But I'm wondering if there is not a simpler way to do this?

Comment: does this `df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated(keep='first')]` answer your question?

Comment: Yes! It does! Thanks a lot