# How to rename duplicated column names in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Quite shortly: I have this DataFrame
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziep5.png)

In the dataframe I have some duplicated columns with different values. How can I fix it so these have different column-names?

```
df_temporary.rename(columns={df_temporary.columns[3]: "OeFG%"}, inplace=True)
df_temporary.rename(columns={df_temporary.columns[11]:"DeFG%"}, inplace=True)
df_temporary.rename(columns={df_temporary.columns[5]: "OTOV%"}, inplace=True)
df_temporary.rename(columns={df_temporary.columns[13]: "DTOV%"}, inplace=True)
df_temporary.rename(columns={df_temporary.columns[8]: "OFT/FGA"}, inplace=True)
df_temporary.rename(columns={df_temporary.columns[-1]: "DFT/FGA"}, inplace=True)

df_temporary
```

I attempted using rename, first with all in one columns in one {}, and then hardcoding each of them  afterwards; both resulting in the same result.

[What I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNQYE.png)

I also tried following this:
[Renaming columns in a Pandas dataframe with duplicate column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774787/renaming-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-with-duplicate-column-names)

Not much success implementing these in my code however.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily just change them column names by changing the value of `df.columns`. A mini-example (I was too lazy to make all the columns, and I'm not sure whether the rename is really what you wanted) for your case would be the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [["Boston Celtics", 51, 31, 0.542, 0.502],
        ["Phoenix Suns", 64, 18, 0.549, 0.510]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Team', 'W', 'L', 'eFG%', 'eFG%'])
df
             Team   W   L   eFG%   eFG%                                                                                                
0  Boston Celtics  51  31  0.542  0.502                                                                                                
1    Phoenix Suns  64  18  0.549  0.510

df.columns = ["Team", "W", "L", "eFG%", "OeFG%"]
df
             Team   W   L   eFG%  OeFG%                                                                                                
0  Boston Celtics  51  31  0.542  0.502                                                                                                
1    Phoenix Suns  64  18  0.549  0.510
```

As you can see, that final column has been renamed to `OeFG%` instead of `eFG%`. You can of course do this for any columns you like!