# Duplicate rows in pandas on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
    Column1   Column2    Column3
1     A                     C
2     A         D   
3     B
```

If the is a "D" in my column2 i want to duplicate the row with is values and reset the index like this :

```
    Column1  Column2    Column3
1     A                    C
2     A         D   
3     A         D   
4     B
```

How do I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First test if duplicated columns names, if necessary [deduplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774787/renaming-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-with-duplicate-column-names) them:

```
print (df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])
```

Then join filtered rows with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and sort indices:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df = (pd.concat([df, df[df['Column2'].eq('D')]])
        .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
        .rename(lambda x: x+1))
print (df)
  Column1 Column2 Column3
1       A     NaN       C
2       A       D     NaN
3       A       D     NaN
4       B     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: thanks for your answer "ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels" how I can avoid?

Comment: @SimonGIS - Is possible create default index first `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`?

Comment: Still get "ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels." I have been stuck for hours on this. Is there an alternative solution? My indexes are not duplicated. I don't quite get it.

Comment: @SimonGIS - Is possible duplciated columns names? `print (df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])` ?